# Need to show selected values along with the un-selected values in select box from database - php codeigniter

Tags: php, html, arrays, codeigniter, select

I'm stuck in something. I'm using codeigniter.

The issue is that I'm working on a custom CMS where I'm working on edit page.

There is two table first one is **tours** and second one is
**tours_cat**

Table name: **tours**
[image: tours]

Table name: **tours_cat**

[image: tours_cat]

I write down some code to get selected tour information from **tour** table and for category I got only the cat_id so I write some code to get category name by using these cat_id.

Following is the code:

```
<select id="tour_category" class="form-control" name="tour_category[]" multiple="multiple" required>
 <?php
  $catIds = explode(',', $tours->tour_page_category);
  foreach ($catIds as $cid) {
   foreach ($categories as $c) {
    if($cid == $c['id'])
     {
       echo '<option value="'.$c['id'].'" selected>'.$c['cat_name'].'</option>';
     }
    }
   }
 ?>
</select>
```

Here are the **$catIds** array which is came from **tour** table:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 6
    [5] => 7
)
```

Here are the **categories** array which is came from **tours_cat**
table

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [cat_name] => Uncategorized
            [cat_summery] => 
            [updated] => 2019-08-11 01:01:02
            [created] => 2019-08-11 01:01:02
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [cat_name] => Family
            [cat_summery] => 
            [updated] => 2019-08-11 01:01:02
            [created] => 2019-08-11 01:01:02
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [cat_name] => Religion & Spirituality
            [cat_summery] => 
            [updated] => 2019-08-11 01:01:02
            [created] => 2019-08-11 01:01:02
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [cat_name] => Wildlife
            [cat_summery] => 
            [updated] => 2019-08-11 01:01:02
            [created] => 2019-08-11 01:01:02
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [cat_name] => Cuisine(Food Tours & Food Walks)
            [cat_summery] => 
            [updated] => 2019-08-11 01:01:02
            [created] => 2019-08-11 01:01:02
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [cat_name] => Boat Trips
            [cat_summery] => 
            [updated] => 2019-08-11 01:01:02
            [created] => 2019-08-11 01:01:02
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [cat_name] => Short Tours(Half Day tours/Walking Tours/Day Excursions)
            [cat_summery] => 
            [updated] => 2019-08-11 01:01:02
            [created] => 2019-08-11 01:01:02
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [cat_name] => Weekend Gateways
            [cat_summery] => 
            [updated] => 2019-08-11 01:01:02
            [created] => 2019-08-11 01:01:02
        )

)
```

**Here are the result that is generated by using above code:**
[image: generated by using above code]

**Here are the result that I wanted to show. I want to show all record but if the category is saved in database, then it should be selected in select box:**
[image: Wanted result]

Sorry guys my question got so long but this is my third question regarding this issue. So that is why I elaborate all the things here with screenshot. It'll be great help if anyone help me.

Comment: I don't clear with your question. Do you want to submit form with multiple selected category and save to database ?

Comment: The quote text formatting is for when you actually quote someone or something. Please stop misusing it to make your own words “look more colorful” or whatever the intention was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating over the categories in the `tours` table, you should iterate over all the categories in the `tours_cat` table, and use the category ids from the `tours` table to decide whether to set `selected` for each option. Something like this:

```
$catIds = explode(',', $tours->tour_page_category);
foreach ($categories as $c) {
    echo "<option value =\"{$c['id']}\"";
    if (in_array($c['id'], $catIds)) echo " selected";
    echo ">{$c['cat_name']}</option>";
}
```

Output

```
<option value ="1">Uncategorized</option> 
<option value ="2" selected>Family</option> 
<option value ="3" selected>Religion&Spirituality</option> 
<option value ="4" selected>Wildlife</option>
<option value ="5" selected>Cuisine(FoodTours&FoodWalks)</option> 
<option value ="6" selected>BoatTrips</option> 
<option value ="7" selected>ShortTours(HalfDaytours/WalkingTours/DayExcursions)</option> 
<option value ="8">WeekendGateways</option>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/OWIjW)

Comment: Hi Nick, This is a great help... I was stuck in with it for last 3 days. Thanks lot once again.